# c# Regex mask for textbox decimal precision 1 min value 1 max value 100

Tags: regex

Does anyone has the regex mask for a textbox where it allows decimal precision 1 with min value of 1 and max value of 100.

Values that need to pass:

0,5

0,1

10,5

99,5

100

basicly every value between 0,1 and 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this pattern a try

```
\d{0,3},?\d*
```

Pattern breakdown:

```
\d{0,3} - 0 to 3 digits
,?      - 0 to 1 comma
\d*     - 0 or more digits
```

Tested at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AqQEp8/1)

Comment: Thx very much! I understand it now!

Answer (score 0):

To match every value between 0,1 and 100 and allow a decimal precision of 1, you could match either: 100 with an optional `,0` or 1 - 99 with an optional 1 decimal precision of 0-9 or match a 0 with 1 decimal precision from 1-9 so it does not match 0,0 using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

[`^(?:[1-9][0-9]?(?:,[0-9])?|0,[1-9]|(?:100(?:,0)?))$`](https://regex101.com/r/tl4UBn/1/)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert start of the line
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[1-9][0-9]?(?:,[0-9]` Match 1 - 99 followed by an optional comma and digit 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `0,[1-9]` Match a zero and a comma followed by a digit 1-9 so 0,0 does not match
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:100(?:,0)?)` Match 100 with an optional comma and 0
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` Assert end of the line

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BZTOBY16145)